# AWS Lambda is duplicating database record, PDF/CSV generation, and email

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS Lambda and backend in general, but I've scoured my code and can't see any duplication of code that might cause duplicate database records, duplicate PDF/CSV generation, and duplicate emails being sent out. I've placed my entire lambda.

```
`   import pymysql
    import boto3
    import subprocess
    import json
    import csv
    import smtplib
    from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
    from email.mime.text import MIMEText
    from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
    from email import encoders
    from datetime import datetime
    import uuid
    import logging
    import pdfkit
    import tempfile
    import os

    # Create an SES client
    ses_client = boto3.client('ses', region_name='us-west-2')

    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    bucket_name = 'www.test.com'
    pdf_template_key = 'ho4-pdf/application.html'

    def generate_pdf_with_data(form_data):
        # Retrieve the PDF template from S3
        response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=pdf_template_key)
        template_content = response['Body'].read()  # No decoding needed for binary data

        # Replace placeholders with actual form data
        for key, value in form_data.items():
            placeholder = f"[{key.upper()}]"
            template_content = template_content.replace(placeholder.encode('utf-8'), str(value).encode('utf-8'))

        # Save the filled-in HTML template to a temporary file
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".html", delete=False) as temp_file:
            temp_file.write(template_content)
            filled_html_path = temp_file.name

        # Convert the filled-in HTML template to a PDF
        filled_pdf_path = '/tmp/filled_form.pdf'
        pdfkit.from_file(filled_html_path, filled_pdf_path,         configuration=pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/opt/bin/wkhtmltopdf'))

        # Remove the temporary HTML file
        os.remove(filled_html_path)
  
        return filled_pdf_path

    def send_email_with_attachment(pdf_file_path, csv_file_path, recipient_email):
        # Define the sender email address
        sender_email = 'support@test.com'

        # Read the PDF file content
        with open(pdf_file_path, 'rb') as file:
            pdf_content = file.read()
        
        # Read the CSV file content
        with open(csv_file_path, 'rb') as file:
            csv_content = file.read()

       # Send the email with the PDF and CSV attachments
        msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
        msg['Subject'] = 'New HO4 form submission received'
        msg['From'] = sender_email
        msg['To'] = recipient_email

        body = 'Please find the attached PDF file and CSV file.'
        msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

        # Attach the CSV content to the email
        csv_filename = 'form_data.csv'
        csv_attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        csv_attachment.set_payload(csv_content)
        encoders.encode_base64(csv_attachment)
        csv_attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', f"attachment; filename={csv_filename}")
        msg.attach(csv_attachment)
    
        # Attach the filled-in PDF to the email
        pdf_attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
        pdf_attachment.set_payload(pdf_content)
        encoders.encode_base64(pdf_attachment)
        pdf_attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename='application.pdf')
        msg.attach(pdf_attachment)
 
        ses_client.send_raw_email(Source=sender_email, Destinations=[recipient_email], RawMessage={'Data': msg.as_string()})

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        # Your 'post to database' code starts here
        logger = logging.getLogger()
        logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        logger.info('Begin Processing')
        logger.info('Received event: %s', event)  # Add this line to check the received event
    
        # Generate timestamp
        timestamp = datetime.now().isoformat()

        # Generate unique number
        unique_number = str(uuid.uuid4())

        # Your code to retrieve form data from the event
        # For example:

        firstName = event.get('firstName', None)
        lastName = event.get('lastName', None)
        phone = event.get('phone', None)
        birthday = event.get('birthday', None)
        email = event.get('email', None)
        zipCode = event.get('zipCode', None)
        city = event.get('city', None)
        tenantState = event.get('tenantState', None)
        community = event.get('community', None)
        address1 = event.get('address1', None)
        unit = event.get('unit', None)
        radioDeductible = event.get('radioDeductible', None)
        radioTier = event.get('radioTier', None)
        packageType = event.get('packageType', None)
        policyDate = event.get('policyDate', None)
        radioAddInterest = event.get('radioAddInterest', None)
        firstName1 = event.get('firstName1', None)
        lastName1 = event.get('lastName1', None)
        address3 = event.get('address3', None)
        termsCheck = event.get('termsCheck', None)
        producer = event.get('producer', None)
        personalcontentscoverage = event.get('personalcontentscoverage', None)
        additionallivingexpense20pctofcontentslimit = event.get('additionallivingexpense20pctofcontentslimit', None)
        limitofliability = event.get('limitofliability', None)
        identityfraud = event.get('identityfraud', None)
        medicalpayments = event.get('medicalpayments', None)
        damagetopropertyofothers = event.get('damagetopropertyofothers', None)
        waterdamage = event.get('waterdamage', None)
        theft = event.get('theft', None)
        replacementcost = event.get('replacementcost', None)
        whpermarkelstateguidelines = event.get('whpermarkelstateguidelines', None)
        increasedmoldgany = event.get('increasedmoldgany', None)
        increasedfungilimitfl = event.get('increasedfungilimitfl', None)

        # ... (retrieve other form data fields as needed)

        # Your code to insert the form data into the database
       with pymysql.connect(host=endpoint, user=username, passwd=password, db=database_name) as connection:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                insert_query = "INSERT INTO lgsandradean.sandytable (time_stamp, unique_number, firstname, lastname, phone, birthday, email, zipcode, city, tenantstate, community, address1, unit, radioDeductible, radioTier, packageType, policyDate, radioAddInterest, firstName1, lastName1, address3, creditName,  termscheck, producer, personal_contents_coverage, additional_living_expense, limit_of_liability, identity_fraud, medical_payments, damage_to_property_of_others, water_damage, theft, replacement_cost, wh_per_markel_state_guidelines, increased_mold_ga_ny, increased_fungi_limit_fl) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
                cursor.execute(insert_query, (timestamp, unique_number, firstName, lastName, phone,     birthday, email, zipCode, city, tenantState, community, address1, unit, radioDeductible, radioTier, packageType, policyDate, radioAddInterest, firstName1, lastName1, address3, termsCheck, producer, personalcontentscoverage, additionallivingexpense20pctofcontentslimit, limitofliability, identityfraud, medicalpayments, damagetopropertyofothers, waterdamage, theft, replacementcost, whpermarkelstateguidelines, increasedmoldgany, increasedfungilimitfl))
            connection.commit()

        logger.info("Successfully inserted data into the RDS database")

        # Your code to create the CSV file from the form data
        csv_data = [
            ['Time Stamp', 'Unique Number', 'First Name', 'Last Name', 'Phone', 'Birthday', 'Email', 'ZIP   Code', 'City', 'Tenant State', 'Community', 'Tenant Address 1', 'Unit', 'Deductible', 'Package Value', 'Package Type', 'Policy Term', 'Additional Interest', 'Add First Name', 'Add Last Name', 'Add Address', 'Terms', 'Producer', 'pcCoverage', 'addLivingExpense', 'liability', 'identityFraud', 'medPay', 'damPropOthers', 'waterDam', 'theft', 'replacement', 'perMarkel', 'incMold', 'incFun'],
            [timestamp, unique_number, firstName, lastName, phone, birthday, email, zipCode, city, tenantState, community, address1, unit, radioDeductible, radioTier, packageType, policyDate, radioAddInterest, firstName1, lastName1, address3, termsCheck, producer, personalcontentscoverage, additionallivingexpense20pctofcontentslimit, limitofliability, identityfraud, medicalpayments, damagetopropertyofothers, waterdamage, theft, replacementcost, whpermarkelstateguidelines, increasedmoldgany, increasedfungilimitfl]
    ]

        csv_file = '/tmp/form_data.csv'  # Path to the temporary CSV file
        with open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerows(csv_data)

        logger.info("Successfully created the CSV file")
    
         filled_pdf_path = generate_pdf_with_data(event)

        # Your code to send the CSV file via email
        recipient_email = 'sandbox@testing.com'
        smtp_username = 'AKIAS3HHBCMT3LCS2EBI'
        smtp_password = 'BFDlA4ZfwP+Yu428UbxN2HBYXz4xRkoDukJ4etn6AlA2'
       send_email_with_attachment(filled_pdf_path, csv_file, recipient_email)

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': 'PDF generated successfully and sent as an email attachment',
    }`
```

I'm hoping someone might have some insight please and thank you.

Comment: What is there in cloudwatch logs? Do you see 2 events ? Also how is this invoked?

Comment: There is an invoke url in an API Gateway that triggers the Lambda. I will check the cloudwatch logs